# $X$ is locally compact, then $X$ is compactly generated.

Tags: general-topology

Im studying Munkres's topology book. In lemma $46.3.,$ “$X$ is locally compact, then $X$ is compactly generated.”

Proof I understand:

Let $A$ be any subset of $X$ s.t. for all compact subspace $C$ of $X$, $A \cap C$ is open in $C$. We have to show that $A$ is open in $X$. Let $x \in A$, and choose any nbd $U$ of $x$ that lies in a compact subspace $C$ of $X,$ i.e. $U$ is open in $C.$ Then by assumption, $A \cap C$ is open in $C \Rightarrow A \cap C \cap U$ is open in $C \cap U \Rightarrow A\cap U$ is open in $U$. But in its last step, 'so $A \cap U$ is open in $X$', he said, i dont understand this part.

Is there some misunderstanding of my thinking? Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: "open in open is open".

$U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, so in Munkres' terminology $U$ is open in $X$ (and contains $x$). If $A \cap U$ is open in $U$ we (by the definition of subspace topology) have an open set $O$ of $X$ such that $O \cap U = A \cap U$. But $O \cap U$ is a finite intersection of open sets of $X$ so open in $X$ and hence so is $A \cap U$.

Similarly we can show "closed in closed is closed" (i.e. if $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ and $B \subseteq A$ is closed in $A$, $B$ is also closed in $X$, etc.)

Comment: Does not [nbd $U$ of $x$ that lies in a compact subspace $C$ of $X$] mean that $U$ is open in $C$? Then What does [lies in a compact subspace $C$ of $X$] mean? Just $U$ is subset of $C$?

Comment: @Han No, it means $U$ is open in $X$ and a subset of $C$. Straight from the definition of local compactness.

Comment: I undetstand! I didn't think about local compactness, so I thought that U may not exist. Thanks